# youtube-dl mp3 download error

Tags: youtube, mp3, youtube-dl

it has been a while I used ubuntu for my daily driver because of me needing VST files in music production, recently picked up this thinkpad.

Anyways, whenever I try to download something from youtube this error shows up

```
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 905, in _decrypt_signature
    video_id, player_url, s
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 797, in _extract_signature_function
    raise ExtractorError('Cannot identify player %r' % player_url)
ExtractorError: Cannot identify player u'/yts/jsbin/player-vflAmElk-/en_US/base.js'; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
 (caused by ExtractorError(u"Cannot identify player u'/yts/jsbin/player-vflAmElk-/en_US/base.js'; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.",)); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

I had been using the same code my past using ubuntu 12.04. what do I miss?

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <url>
```

Comment: Have you already tried updating `youtube-dl`?

Comment: @wjandrea doing the python thing solved the issue mate, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hanging around for the solution pip installation solved the issue

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```